# Unable to properly install magento 2.2.5 locally on 127.0.0.1 even localhost

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce, magento2, failed-installation

I have a big installation problem on magento 2.2.5
Can not correctly install the solution because I have errors in the console js.

Do you have solutions and have you already encountered this type of problem?
I followed this tutorial but it did not give anything
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222341/refused-to-execute-script-from-url-after-moving-from-dev-to-production

Here are my mistakes, plus it reams a lot to load the page ...

[image: Installation problem magento 2.2.5]

thank you in advance

Comment: Issue is related to htacess or mod rewrite. Please ensure both are perfect.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your comment.
The mod_rewrite is activated and the htaccess is original I did not touch anything after the installation